# how to do this Python interpolation in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, vector, interpolation

I need to convert this piece of Python code in MATLAB, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

[python loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDsR7.png)

```
T = 1968,
F = 1025,
used_freq = 22050,
freqs = 1621 x 1 vector,
log_scale_spec = 1968 x 1025 matrix,
cent_spec was initialized with zeros = 1968 x 1621 matrix,
and the "linspace(0, used_freq, F)" operation gives a 1025 x 1 vector
```

The interpolation seems to be a cubic (k = 3).

I just don't know how to structure all of this together as a for loop in MATLAB.
I tried something like this so far:

[matlab loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xdg2.png)

The f represents the operation " linspace(0, used_freq, F)' " 
Notice in Matlab, it has to be transposed with ' .

I am trying to make it work in Matlab, I am not sure how to do this, probably either missing some indexing in the loop or maybe some of the vectors/matrices need to be transposed or a combination of those.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Copy-paste the code into the edit box. Images are not accessible to everyone and are not searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T = 1968,
F = 1025,
used_freq = 22050,
```

The line below is the wrong statement. The higher dimension of *freqs* must be smaller than *F*. I can add that *freqs* must contain indices, not frequencies.

```
freqs = 1621 x 1 vector - wrong
freqs = F< x 1 vector - right
log_scale_spec = T x F matrix,
```

You can delete line below because _cent_spec_ evals outside of loop

```
cent_spec=zeros(T,F<)
f=linspace(0, used_freq, F);

for t=1:T
    Sp(:,t)=interp1(f,log_scale_spec(:,t),'cubic');
end
cent_spec=Sp(:,freqs);
```